# How to get text node from xml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I want to extract some data from xml.

I have this xml:

```
<root>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Even more text</p>
    <span class="bla bla">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span> 19.95
    </span>
</root>
```

and then I run this php code

```
$xml =  simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$obj = json_decode($json);
print_r($obj);
```

and the result is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [p] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some text
            [1] => Even more text
        )

    [span] => stdClass Object
        (
            [@attributes] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [class] => bla bla
                )

            [span] => EUR
        )
)
```

How do I get the missing string "19.95"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't convert XML into JSON/an array. It means that you loose information and features.

SimpleXML is litmit, it works with basic XML, but it has problems with thing like mixed nodes. DOM allows for an easier handling in this case.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<root>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <p>Even more text</p>
    <span class="bla bla">
        <span class="currency">EUR</span> 19.95
    </span>
</root>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach($xpath->evaluate('/root/span[@class="bla bla"]') as $span) {
  var_dump(
    $xpath->evaluate('string(span[@class="currency"][1])', $span),
    $xpath->evaluate(
      'number(span[@class="currency"][1]/following-sibling::text()[1])',
      $span
    )
  );
}
```

Xpath is an expression language to fetch parts of an DOM (Think SQL for XML). PHP has several method to access it. `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` allows to fetch nodes as arrays of SimpleXMLElement objects. `DOMXpath::query()` allows you to fetch node lists. Only `DOMXpath::evaluate()` allows to fetch node lists and scalar values.

In the example `/root/span[@class="bla bla"]` fetches all `span` element nodes that have the given class attribute. For each of the nodes it then fetches the `span` with the class currency as a string. The third expression fetches the first following sibling text node of the `currency` span as a number.

Comment: While this includes some neat tricks with XPath, it's massively overkill for the task described. SimpleXML doesn't "have problems with" this XML at all, except for the incomplete output of `print_r`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust the debug output, don't convert to JSON or an array, and don't overthink the problem.

Outputting this string is as simple as navigating to the element and echoing it:

```
echo $xml->span;
```

Or to get it into a variable, explicitly cast to string:

```
$foo = (string)$xml->span
```

Or if you want to use XPath like in ThW's answer, you could find the span using `//span[@class="bla bla"]` and echo that (note that `->xpath()` returns an array, so you want element 0 of that array):

```
echo $xml->xpath('//span[@class="bla bla"]')[0];
```